# server is receiving two requests on single request sent by client

Tags: python

I have written a web server in python which simply sends the response "Website Coming Soon!" to the client (client is a web-browser), the problem is that when a client sends a single request like:

```
http://localhost:13555
```

the server is recieving two requests which are:

**1st Request:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:13555
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0
.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**2nd Request:**

```
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:13555
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:13555/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

but I want only 1st request to be received at the server because when I am doing some operation on the client-request the 2nd request is creating some problems, I cannot use builtin libraries to write the web-server, so please solve my problem.

**The server code is:**

```
import socket
import re
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 13555

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print ("Serving HTTP on port %s ..." % PORT)

while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(2048)
    print(request)
    response = "Website Coming Soon!"       
    http_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"+"Content-Type: text/html\n"+"\n"+"<html><body>"+response+"</body></html>\n"
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: If you don't want to handle the favicon request, can't you just drop it? Could you post your code, the tool/framework you used to do this?

Comment: I have posted the code of the web-server

Comment: "the 2nd request is creating some problems" - huh? what's the problem?

Comment: If the second request is causing problems. I'd question the robustness of your server. All browsers will probably send this, so your server is best to have code handle it or ignore it.

Comment: How is `GET /favicon.ico` different from `GET /any/other/bogus/file.name`?  You'll have to handle the second case anyway, so the first is as good as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers automatically request a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) (the little image on the left of the url).

An easy way to deal with it (without parsing the request or setting up a router) would be to see if the request contains the substring `"favicon"`, but that is obviously not very robust.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add a condition like :

```
while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(2048)
    print(request)
    if request_does_not_contain_favicon(request):
        response = "Website Coming Soon!"       
        http_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"+"Content-Type: text/html\n"+"\n"+"<html><body>"+response+"</body></html>\n"
        client_connection.sendall(http_response)
        client_connection.close()
```

?

You would have to code a function to detect the url to not serve, but I don't know what exactly is in your request object.